# C++ Pthread/SFML Music - Error AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed

Tags: c++, pthreads, sfml

I have a project that is to recode the Bomberman and I implemented the sf :: Music for music added to main menu but I come across an error:

```
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

And it's relied to this :
void    *pthreadSound(void *);

```
int     main(int, char **){
  GameEngine    *game = new GameEngine();
  pthread_attr_t        attr;
  pthread_t     sound;
  void          *retval;

  try {
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if (!game->initialize())
      throw ErrorBomberman("Game fail initialisation", "main");
    game->m_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    game->setLock(true);
    pthread_create(&sound, &attr, pthreadSound, (void *)game);
    game->ChangeState(IntroState::Instance());
    while (game->Running()){
      game->HandleEvents();
      game->update();
      game->draw();
    }
    game->Cleanup();
    pthread_join(sound, &retval);
  } catch (ErrorBomberman const &e) {
    std::cerr << "Error caught in " << e.getComponent() << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void            *pthreadSound(void *game){
  sf::Music     music1;

  if (!music1.OpenFromFile("./ressources/Bomberman_Theme.ogg"))
    std::cout << "Erreur : load" << std::endl;
  music1.Play();
  while (((GameEngine *)game)->getLock()){
  }
  std::cout << "Stop" << std::endl;
  music1.Stop();
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return (NULL);
}
```

Maybe, it's because the Stop doesn't work ? I don't know. If you have an idea, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Music.php):

> As a sound stream, a music is played in its own thread in order not to block the rest of the program. This means that you can leave the music alone after calling `play()`, it will manage itself very well.

So you don't really need to create another thread to play the music.

Comment: Yes, but i use sf::Music because the song it's a music. So i need ti use SoundStream ?

Comment: No, `sf::Music` already inherits from `sf::SoundStream`. Just play it like you did but without creating new thread. See the docs for the explanation.